# jQuery set img src to own rel attribute in one line

Tags: jquery

I want to start loading all gallery images only once I click a button like this:

```
<div class=".gallery-pictures">
    <img rel="image1url" />
    <img rel="image2url" />
    ...
</div>

$('.gallery-pictures img').attr( 'src', $(this).attr('rel') );
```

However, obviously `$(this)` is not the image so the `rel` attribute wouldn't be the correct one. So I'm wondering if there's a to set all these without having to use:

```
$(selector + ' img').each(function(index, image)
{
    $(image).attr( 'src', $(image).attr('rel') );
});
```

Comment: .attr accepts a function as its second argument that will be called for each image. The return value will be set as the attribute's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the jQuery setter functions accept a function as the argument. They call the function on each selected element, passing the old value of whatever is being set as the argument, setting `this` to the element, and using the return value as the new value.

```
$(select + ' img').attr('src', function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

This is basically a shortcut for using `.each()`.

Comment: Ok so basically there is no shorter way of doing this huh? Ok, fair enough, I'll roll with that. Thanks friend!

Comment: You could always define your own function for it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$.each()` if you need the context of the item itself to compute the value, in your case you do since the value changes per item.

Comment: He already showed how to do it with `.each()`, the question is whether there's a shortcut.